# regex replace words

Tags: php, regex, replace, expression

I have a string `$str` defined like this:

> `$str = "Horosho byt' tihoney 23 Sen 2012 14:00 | 20:20 | 00:30 24 Sen 2012 09:30 | 14:00  Obitel' zla: Vozmezdie 3D 23 Sen 2012 16:10 | 20:25 | 22:25 Osobo opasny 23 Sen 2012 18:00 24 Sen 2012 11:30 | 18:00 25 Sen 2012 11:30 | 18:00 26 Sen 2012 11:30 | 18:00 Patrul' 23 Sen 2012 20:10 | 22:20 24 Sen 2012 11:50 | 20:10"`

and I want to surround the words with `<br>` tags; for example, `Horosho byt' tihoney` would become `<br>Horosho byt' tihoney<br>`, and `Obitel' zla: Vozmezdie 3D` would become `<br>Obitel' zla: Vozmezdie 3D<br>`.

What I have so far:

```
preg_replace("/(?<=\s)([\p{L}*?]{3,})(?=\s[0-9]{2}\s)/u", "<br>$1<br>", $str);
```

Comment: Would you please tag this post with the name of the language that you are using as well as editing your post's content so it is clear what text you want to change? Currently, the <br> tags are actually getting evaluated and creating new lines. By surrounding your text in your example with backticks, you can eliminate this problem.

Comment: Do you really need 2 `<br>`? One should be enough, I think.

Comment: Do you need to match `Osobo opasny` and `Patrul'` too?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so here is my solution. It's not exactly what you specified, but it solves your problem. The dates and times seem much more regular than the names (because the latter might contain digits, apostrophes and colons... and who know what more). So I figured, enclosing the dates and times in `<br/>` would be just as good (of course you have to add another `<br/>` right at the start and remove one from the end, but that's less of a problem, I guess. So here is the regex that finds strings of dates and times and encloses them (and their surrounding spaces) in `<br/>`:

```
$newStr = preg_replace("/(\s\d{1,2}\s[A-Z][a-z][a-z]\s\d{4}|\s\d{2}:\d{2}|\s\|)+\s?/", "<br/>$0<br/>", $str);
```

I assumed that the day of your dates might have 1 or 2 digits (couldn't tell from the example string) and that all your months are 1 upper-case and 2 lower-case characters.

**EDIT:** I added a `?` at the end to make it work with the last time in the string.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I couldn't guess to enclose the dates and times in tag.

Comment: No problem. If this answers your question, please accept and/or upvote the answer.

Comment: anyone know how to surround all WORDS (not just dates and times) with br tags?

Comment: @johnywhy what's a "word"? non-space characters? search for `\S+`. And have a look at a good [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). This seems really basic. ;)

Comment: got my answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/726807/how-to-replace-words-with-vbscript-regex-and-vba